# agrupar por horas en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

hola a todos existe alguna forma de que pueda agrupar por horas en sql

por ejemplo que me agrupe los datos de la 1 pm y luego los de las 2 pm y 3 pm etc..

```html
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Fecha, 108),
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_Disco' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_Disco',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_Rim' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_Rim',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_Assy' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_Assy',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_ED' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_ED',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_TC' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_TC'
from HistoricoContador
where CONVERT (date,Fecha) = dateadd(day, -0,CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, Fecha, 108)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, Fecha, 108) ASC
```

Comment: Si puedes utilizar datepart(hour,fecha), para realizarlo. Si quieres un ejemplo, tendrás que poner, un ejemplo simple con datos, de lo que obtienes, con esa consulta y sobre todo lo que deseas conseguir.

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `DATEPART` lo puedes realizar sin problemas

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) as Hora,
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_Disco' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_Disco',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_Rim' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_Rim',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_Assy' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_Assy',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_ED' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_ED',
SUM(CASE WHEN Linea = 'Linea_TC' THEN Qty else 0 END) as 'Linea_TC'
from HistoricoContador
where CONVERT (date,Fecha) = dateadd(day, -0,CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha)
ORDER BY Hora ASC
```